# Border image for specific border

Tags: css

I'm created a triangle using CSS, It works fine. Now I want to use an image instead of colors for border, But it does not work. I want border image only for `border-top`.
**It's original CSS:**

```
.triangle-down
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 87px solid transparent;
    border-right: 87px solid transparent;
    border-top: 150px solid #14A2E0;

}
```

**It's modified CSS to use an image:**

```
.triangle-down
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 87px solid transparent;
    border-right: 87px solid transparent;
    border-top: 150px solid;
    -moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Old Firefox */
    -webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
    -o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
    border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;   
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MnPLh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get more or less what you want. Long story short, transparent will not work with borders. You need to superimpose 2 css elements. http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/TfV8K/

```
.triangle-down
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 87px solid white;
    border-right: 87px solid white;
    border-top: 150px solid transparent;
    margin-top:153px;

}


.triangle-down1
{
    top:150px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-image:url(http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png) 30 30 round;
    -moz-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Old Firefox */
   -webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
   -o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */ 
    border-left: 87px solid transparent;
    border-right: 87px solid transparent;
    border-top: 150px solid transparent;  
}​

<div class='triangle-down1'></div>
<div class='triangle-down'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the trick to making a CSS based triangle use the border-image property and actually get the expected appearance seems to lay largely in the image used.

The CSS I used last time I did this goes something like this.

```
#pyramid{
    display:inline-block;
    border: 150px outset transparent;
    border-top:0px outset transparent;
    border-left:150px outset transparent;
    border-right:150px outset transparent;
    border-image: url("pyramid_border_image.png") 150 150 150 150 stretch stretch;
    overflow:visible;
    height  :1px;   width:1px;
    padding :0; margin:-1px;
    }
```

I'm sure that could be thinned out some , but at the time I just wanted to see if I could do it, however I might be revisiting it soon as I want a pyramid for one of my css3 3d things.

As I was mentioning , the trick seems at least to me to be mostly in the image , specifically the corner pieces for the lower left and lower right corners in the border image. These corners themselves need to have their squares contain 1/2 transparent and 1/2 pattern at the appropriate 45 degree angles for the two bottom corners of the triangle.

With the properly made image , it's fairly straight forward after that.